# R Leaflet custom markers for a categorical variable: images not shown

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to make a leaflet map in R with custom markers for a categorical variable.
I used the example  at https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html as a starting point, but as it uses a numerical variable I adapted as follows:

```
 logos <- iconList(
 LA = makeIcon("~/mydata/la_logo.png","la_logo-15@2x.png", 15, 15),
 CO = makeIcon("~/mydata/co_logo.jpg","co_logo-15@2x.png", 15,15),
 CF = makeIcon("~/mydata/cf_logo.png","cf_logo-15@2x.png", 15,15),
 NN = makeIcon("~/mydata/nn_logo.png","nn_logo-15@2x.png", 15,15)
 )

leaflet(data) %>%
 addTiles() %>%
 addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
 addMarkers(icon = ~logos[var]
 )
```

In data, the variable var has the values "LA", "CO", "CF" and "NN" and lat and lon (latitude and longitude respectively).

My map shows as follows:[image]

I have verified that the images are in the url declared.
Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: your questions is unclear to me, what is your desired output?

Comment: My intention is to show each ocurrence of the variable "var" with the correspondent logo (image) in the map. In the dataframe each row has  values for var, lat and long. var has 4 posible values (LA, CF, CO, NN) and there are several ocurrences of each one, but with different lat and lon.

Comment: please provide a url link to your icons so we can reproduce and provide some reproducible data if you're seeking help on SO

Comment: logos <- iconList(
      LA = makeIcon("http://grupomasmasegosa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/hyundai.jpg", "la_logo-15@2x.png", 15, 15),
      CO = makeIcon("http://grupomasmasegosa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/jeep-logo-icono.png", "co_logo-15@2x.png", 15,15),
      CF = makeIcon("http://grupomasmasegosa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/kia-motors.png", "cf_logo-15@2x.png", 15,15),
      NN = makeIcon("http://grupomasmasegosa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/chevrolet-logo.png", "nn_logo-15@2x.png", 15,15)
)

Comment: all the links you've posted are 404 errors...

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to include full code. here are the links.   http://grupomasmasegosa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/hyundai.jpg  http://grupomasmasegosa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/kia-motors.png    http://grupomasmasegosa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/jeep-logo-icono.png   http://grupomasmasegosa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/chevrolet-logo.png

Comment: and your data....

Comment: var       lat       lon
 1:  CO-54.81790 -68.33530
 2:  CF -54.81478 -68.32578
 3:  LA -54.81330 -68.32702
 4:  LA -54.80924 -68.31342
 5:  LA -54.80407 -68.30217
 6:  LA -54.79826 -68.27745
 7:  LA -54.50444 -67.18861
 8:  NN -53.79251 -67.72149
 9:  LA -53.78630 -67.70084
10:  CF -53.78498 -67.70316
11:  LA -53.77885 -67.71814
12:  CF -53.77372 -67.72155
13:  CO-53.76949 -67.71694
14:  LA -51.64111 -69.22923
15:  LA -51.63866 -69.22013
16:  LA -51.63544 -69.20936
17:  LA -51.63219 -69.19812
18:  NN-51.62891 -69.23756
19:  CF -51.62722 -69.24734

Comment: thats not a reproducible example!  How am I suppose to use that! see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for help. You're making it really hard for us to help you. Please follow the SO etiquette...